# PHP: Direct access to an element in an array of objects

Tags: php

I am trying to output a set of data, and I have, due to my `LEFT OUTER JOIN` got multiple rows per match.

I'm using a positive look ahead to see if the next row is the same id as the first. However the return from the database class returns an array of objects.

```
array(7) {
          [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (8) {
                                      ["dom_id"]=>string(1) "3"
                                      ["domain"]=>string(11) "example.com"
                                      ["status"]=>string(7) "Invalid"
                                      ["expiry"]=>string(10) "2010-07-20"
                                      ["remaining"]=>string(6) "0 Days"
                                      ["rem_id"]=>NULL
                                      ["alert_type"]=>NULL
                                      ["contact"]=>NULL
  }
//etc
```

I am getting the following error, `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

My code is as follows,

```
echo $domains[$k+1]->alert_type;
```

I know that I could assign the new dimension to a variable and access that as an object, but for the sake of neatness I'd rather access it directly.

Is this possible? ..and if it is, how do I approach it?

Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

- fetch as `array` instead of `stdClass` *or*
- [typecast to `(array)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) *or*
- use a custom class that implements [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

Comment: Eish, I'll just assign it to a variable then :) Cheers for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$domains` is your `stdClass` object which you wish was an array, you could try using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
echo $domains->{$k+1}->alert_type;
```

The real problem though is that you have a bunch of `stdClass` objects. Are you storing these in a session and then reading them later, or are you neglecting to include a file or something... ?

Comment: I don't think it's missing the database class, or my queries wouldn't work. It's just a straight up db -> display page